# how to convert Stream<T> to return only T?

Tags: flutter, dart, rxdart

I have a function named **checkAuth()** in my **APIService class** which checks whether there is token  in my SharedPreferences. if there is a token it returns **AuthenticatedState** or else it returns **NotAuthenticatedState**. Running the below code doesn't have any **AuthenticationState** at the start. so I tried to add the **checkAuth()** in the seeded but it throws an error that **Stream<`AuthenticationState`> can't be assigned to AuthenticationState**.

How can I convert Stream`<AuthenticationState>` to AuthenticationState?

```
BehaviorSubject<AuthenticationState> _authStatus =
      BehaviorSubject<AuthenticationState>();    

Stream<AuthenticationState> get loginStream => _authStatus;

  submit() async {
    final String validEmail = _email.value;
    final String validPassword = _password.value;
    APIService.login(validEmail, validPassword)
        .then((onValue) {
      if (onValue is Success) {
        _authStatus.add(AuthenticatedState());
      } else {
        _authStatus.add(NotAuthenticatedState());
      }
    });
  }
```

This is for UI

```
return StreamBuilder(
      stream: stream.loginStream,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            height: double.infinity,
            color: Theme.of(context).cardColor,
            child: Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                valueColor: const AlwaysStoppedAnimation(Colors.white),
              ),
            ),
          );
        }
        if (snapshot.hasError || snapshot.data is NotAuthenticatedState) {
          return Login();
        }
        if (snapshot.data is AuthenticatedState) {
          return App();
        }
        return Container(width: 0, height: 0);
      },
    );
```

It doesn't display any thing on the screen because it doesn't have a value at start , I think so ...

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to user `StreamBuilder` to get **T** form Stream<**T**>, because of the time cost, It's take a time when read data with `SharedPreferences`.

```
StreamBuilder<T>(    /// T represent the type of fetched data, Assuming it's String
    stream: /// put the stream var in there or function with stream as a return
    builder:(BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<T> snapshot){
        if(snapshot.hasData) /// Check If it finishes fetching the data
            retrun Text( snapshot.data ); /// snapshot.data variable store the data that fetched
    }
);
```

Check this page form more:

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html

/// Update answer

You have to initial the data on SharedPreferences with:

```
SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((SharedPreferences sp) {
      bool _testValue = sharedPreferences.getBool(spKey);
      // will be null if never previously saved
      if (_testValue == null) {
        _testValue = false;
        // set an initial value
      }
    });
```

Comment: Are you receive null value in first time opening?

Comment: it shows a blank screen cause snapshot.hasdata is false

Comment: Check the SharedPreferences initial value.

Comment: if I print the returned value of checkAuth() its returning NotAuthenticatedState

Comment: What you mean when you return `App` and `Login` class? Are you mean push new widget?

Comment: if it returns App then you are into the app otherwise it returns login page

Comment: I think you have to use: `Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => Login()));`